# Ruby Motion: Removing a Ruby Class Completely from Object Space

Tags: ruby, testing, rubymotion

I'm running into a brick wall testing class redefinitions and just don't know how to approach it. Here's the scenario I'm testing (this is not Core Data):

- Application is run with a model in version 1
- Eager programmer modifies model by adding/removing/redefining columns
- Application is run with the model in version 2

Where I'm running into problems is in simulating the actual removal of the application from memory and rebuilding of it from scratch. This is important because a number of model-specific things are set up when the `MotionModel::Model` module is included, and that only happens once: When the module is included in the class. Here is what I felt might work:

```
  it "column removal" do
      class Removeable
        include MotionModel::Model
        columns       :name => :string, :desc => :string
      end


      @foo = Removeable.create(:name=> 'Bob', :desc => 'who cares anyway?')


      Removeable.serialize_to_file('test.dat')

      @foo.should.respond_to :desc

      Object.send(:remove_const, :Removeable)  # Should remove all traces of Removeable
      class Removeable
        include MotionModel::model             # Should include this again instead
        columns       :name => :string,        # of just reopening the old Removeable
                      :address => :string      # class
      end


      Removeable.deserialize_from_file # Deserialize old data into new model


      Removeable.length.should == 1
      @bar = Removeable.first
      @bar.should.respond_to :name
      @bar.should.respond_to :address      
      @bar.should.not.respond_to :desc


      @bar.name.should == 'Bob'
      @bar.address.should == nil
    end
  end
```

Unfortunately, `Object.send(:remove_const, :Removeable)` does not do what I'd hoped it would, and Ruby just thinks it can reopen `Removeable` and not run the `self.included()` method of the `MotionModel::Model` module.

Any ideas on how to emulate creation of this class from scratch in the context of a spec example?

Comment: Probably a dumb suggestion, but did you try a string instead of a symbol? "Removable"?

Comment: I'm using `Object.send(:remove_const, :Foo) if defined?(Foo)` just fine in my commits to MotionModel, maybe this is no longer an issue? Perhaps the 1.35 release of RubyMotion's caching fixes have solved this.

Answer (score 3):

I'd try working with anonymous classes (you'd have to tell MotionModel the table name).

Fictional example:

```
model_before_update = Class.new do
  # This tells MotionModel the name of the class (don't know if that actually exists)
  table_name "SomeTable"
  include MotionModel::Model
  columns       :name => :string, :desc => :string
end
```

You do not remove the class at all, you just define another (anonymous) class with the same table name.

```
model_after_update = Class.new do
  table_name "SomeTable"
  include MotionModel::model
  columns       :name => :string,
                :address => :string
end
```

Thinking of it, if there is a table_name setter like above, you don't even need to use anonymous classes, in case that does not work with RubyMotion.

Comment: This is a good thought. I think it would break some code and be less intuitive than what I had planned, however a table_name setter is always a good idea.